# Python: RoboBrowser TypeError: 'NoneType'

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, robobrowser

I am attempting to scrape pricing info for certain items on Tessco.com
I found RoboBrowser, and a few tutorials. Following the tutorial, I have an error, where the poster does not. I am not sure what needs to be modified to correct the issue.

Code is as follows:

```
import re
import config
from robobrowser import RoboBrowser
br = RoboBrowser(history=True)

br.open("https://www.tessco.com/login")
form = br.get_form()
form['userID'] = config.TESSCO_USERNAME
form['password'] = config.TESSCO_PASSWORD
br.submit_form(form)
```

Looking at the inspector in Google Chrome, I see an ID of `userID` and `password` for the sections that need user input.

I am assuming there is a problem with how RoboBrowser is looking for the form, and returning None.

My error message is:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-58-6c3d8fcb718d> in <module>
      1 form = br.get_form()
----> 2 form['userID'] = config.TESSCO_USERNAME
      3 form['password'] = config.TESSCO_PASSWORD
      4 br.submit_form(form)

TypeError: 'NoneType' object does not support item assignment
```

I am very unaware of what is wrong. Any tips to point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://robobrowser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#robobrowser.browser.RoboBrowser.get_form

A quote from their website:

> Returns:  BeautifulSoup tag if found, else None

This means that RoboBrowser can't find a form on that website.

It cannot find a form because the form in https://www.tessco.com/login is loaded through javascript.

Since RoboBrowser doesn't execute javascript, the form was never loaded, and therfore RoboBrowser can't find it.

You might want to try something like [selenium](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/), which actually runs a background browser, rather than just loading the HTML

Comment: Thank you! I will look into Selenium. 

As an update, last night I printed the form via 
form = br.get_forms() 
print(form) 

and Python returned an empty dictionary. Your comment makes much sense. 
Thanks again.